# Cannot create kinesis analytics application

Tags: analytics, amazon-kinesis

While creating Kinesis Analytics application it successfully discovered my schema based on the data. However, when I hit save and continue, I get following error

> Error updating application There was an issue updating your
>   application. Error message: 1 validation error detected: Value 'C' at
>   'input.inputSchema.recordColumns.2.member.name' failed to satisfy
>   constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+

my sample record is below

> {"reported": {"timestamp": "1482231365", "C": "40", "id": "D_aa-bb"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I overlooked the error message. Found the solution, hope it might help someone.

The auto detected schema name was the issue. From the sample record, the auto detected column name was `C` and the regex says it should contains atleast two characters. After editing the schema manually with two characters it succeeded.

There was another issue though, the auto detected column name `timestamp` is a reserved keyword, which we need to change.